# Appending QString to a QByteArray as a hexadecimal instead characters?

Tags: arrays, list, qt, append, qbytearray

A peculiar thing that I encountered is that in a loop that I am doing where I am populating a `QByteArray` with a chunks of a `QStringList`. To be more precise, the `QStringList` takes a standard `QString` and splits it into smaller bits on every time it encounters a "-" within the string. Ergo, if a `QString` containing `"A1-B2-C3-D4-E5"`, it would populate the list as small chunks (`list[0]="A1",list[1]="B2",list[2]="C3",...`). However, I need those bytes to populate a `QByteArray` and when I use a loop it only takes the chars of it and fills the `QByteArray` as `bytearray[0]="A",bytearray[1]="1",bytearray[2]="2"` and so on. Considering the code I am using, I am wondering what wrong has happened?

Here is the code:

```
QStringList inputArray = input.split('-');
                QByteArray output;

                for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.count(); i++)
                {
                     output.append(inputArray.at(i).toLatin1());
                }

                ui->lineEdit->setText(output);
```

Comment: Your question is -- to me at least -- very unclear.  The code, as posted, does *exactly* what I would expect resulting in `output` being equivalent to `QByteArray("A1B2C3D4E5")`.

Comment: `I am wondering what wrong has happened?` you and everyone else.

Comment: What I want to happen is to have the byte bits to be added in their entirety - currently I have the QByteArray populated like this bytearray[0]="A",bytearray[1]="1",bytearray[2]="B", while I would need it to contain its full values ie bytearray[0]="A1",bytearray[1]="B2",bytearray[2]="C3".

Comment: Sounds like you really want a [`QByteArrayList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearraylist.html) rather than a simple `QByteArray`.

Comment: Well, hate to break it to you, but a byte is one char. Now if your char pairs contain hexadecimal symbols only, that is 0-9 and A-F you could convert them to bytes as they would be able to fit in a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qDebug() << QByteArray("ACDC"); // outputs "ACDC"
```

Provided that those character pairs are indeed hexadecimals, you need to tell specify that:

```
qDebug() << QByteArray::fromHex("ACDC"); // outputs "\xAC\xDC"
```

The former byte array will be 4 bytes long, whereas the latter will only be 2 bytes long, as each char pair is decoded as hexadecimal.

Comment: So there is no way to have the QStringList chunks treated as hex values?

Comment: That's exactly what `QByteArray::fromHex()` does, how is it not clear? Just change the code to `output.append(QByteArray::fromHex(inputArray.at(i).toLatin1()));`

Comment: It worked after a "clean all" and "qmake". Thank you!